# frequent crashs using ubuntu 17.10

Tags: kernel, 17.10, hardware

I have recently installed ubuntu 17.10 on `DELL optiplex 3020` and I increase the amount of RAM from 8GB to 16GB. But I got frequently crashs in many applications such as: chromium, firefox , visual Studio. Sometimes all the session freezed and I have to reboot the pc.
I run the command `memtester 16G 1` and I got this result:

```
Loop 1/1:


Stuck Address       : ok         
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok         
  Block Sequential    : ok         
  Checkerboard        : ok         
  Bit Spread          : ok         
  Bit Flip            : ok         
  Walking Ones        : ok         
  Walking Zeroes      : ok         
  8-bit Writes        : ok
  16-bit Writes       : ok
```

the output of `echo $?`:

```
0
```

I'm able today to boot the sytem after the 4 fourth test and I got a black screen when I tried to reboot the pc contains many information such as `kernel panic not sync`.
Does this problem is due to the hardware or the image of ubuntu that I installed?

Below is the syslog's file:
[syslog](https://pastebin.com/DxaP00sW)

Comment: Note the *exact* time of a freeze. After rebooting, look for errors at that time in /var/log/syslog. Whether or not there are errors logged at all is an important diagnostic clue. If any errors are logged, those errors are also particularly useful to understand the underlying problem.

Comment: @user535733 now the `/var/log/syslog` is empty.

Comment: 'Empty' meaning 'nothing useful' or meaning 'absolutely zero content at all'?

Comment: @user535733 I added the syslog contains a crash in firefox.